# can't join faces?

Tags: faces

I am trying to make a UV map for these stairs. I created the stairs by join multiple blocks which you can see in the image. When I just select the faces on one side and select 'F' to 'Make Edge/Face' it doesn't make them into one face. I have been able to do this before on another object but can't seem to get it to do it on this object. What am I doing wrong?

When I join I would prefer it to just get rid of all interior edges anyways so it is just one object. Is there some setting I am missing?

[image: face_issue]

Comment: maybe remove the doubles before? If it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5537" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5537/)

Comment: I tried removing doubles and it kept saying no verticies were removed. I don't know if there is a way to remove doubles otherwise. I uploaded my file. I have been trying to tackle this problem for a day. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Actually, that first file is when I was trying to delete interior faces to see if that would help, and then join. Below is a link with the original objects before deleting any faces or joining.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5538" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5538/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't join the faces because all your cubes are different objects. Maybe you thought it was one and unique object because in Blender 2.8 you can edit several objects at the same time, but they are still not one object. Therefore, to merge the faces, you need to join your different cubes with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, delete inner faces, remove doubles (increase the *Merge Distance* value of the *Remove Doubles* on the bottom of the *Tools* panel if it's not enough), then fill the faces.

Comment: I can send you the file with merged objects. I uploaded before I merged the objects in case I did something wrong there. Even after I join all of them into a single object, I still can't connect faces. Below is the file with the joined object.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5539" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5539/)

Comment: I am using version 2.7 because that is the version that works with the other software I am using in conjunction with blender.

Comment: Edit: I thought I got it to work, but still not working :(

Comment: you need to delete all the inner faces + remove doubles, increase the Merge Distance value of the Remove Doubles if it's not enough

Comment: I am used to using solidworks so blender is new to me and I find it a lot less intuitive. I feel like this is a stupid way to make this kind of object in the first place. Is there a way I can make a path and just specify all the verticies? I have found the extrude button, but can only create a cube, plane, sphere, etc... I have been googling for an answer but I feel like I am not searching the correct terms because I can't find an answer. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: if you work a lot on hardsurfaces I recommend the Speedflow addon which is fantastic, but maybe you need to get a bit more familiar with Blender before. Once you'll be you'll find it very intuitive (I'm still not a fan of 2.8 but maybe I need to get used to).

Comment: search for some speedflow tutorials on youtube and you'll see how it simplify the hardsurface works

Comment: Blender is a polygonal modeler, it doesn't work anywhere near like Solidworks, which is a CAD program using solid modeling based on parametric feature-based workflow. It's really two different worlds, you don't even think the same way. You can kind of do some CAD in Blender, but with polygonal modeling tools and only in that paradigm. So if you can't get used to that, consider going back to CAD softwares. There are a bunch of free & opensource SW alternatives: https://alternativeto.net/software/solidworks/?license=opensource

Answer (score 1):

You can build this using blocks, but in this case your model will not be solid. 
Blender is not a CAD program and will not automatically delete inner faces. So think about other ways to build this shape. For example, using extruding:

[image]

So start with grid, delete all faces that you don't need, when extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>) After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to make sure, that normals are correct

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the simplest case:

- In Edit Mode, you can duplicate a cube, and snap it to itself.
- Then hit 'Remove Doubles'. The system obliges, and removes 4 coincident vertices.
- But it does **not** remove internal faces.

(At this stage, you could still Select > Select All by Trait > Select Internal Faces, catch the one on the inside, and delete it)

- Now hit <kbd>F</kbd> on the front pair of faces.
- Again, the system obliges, and removes the central edge from the *definition* of the front faces.
- But it has not removed the edge from the definition of the internal face, so it is still there.

Now the 'inside' face is not even recognized as internal any more - and the mesh is truly pathological, and hard to fix.

[image]

So alarm bells should go off in your head whenever you think you might be creating internal faces - avoid them altogether. A possible route to an Ngon-sided staircase is as follows, where the third step is an  <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve of edges, all selected.

[image]